# Is there a way in code to recognize in Salesforce the type of licenses of a sandbox? (Developer, Developer Pro, Partial Copy, Full)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to create a class to set specific configurations on a sandbox depending on the type of license the sandbox has after the sandbox is Refreshed.

All I've been able to do is to tell if it is Production or a Sandbox but not what kind of sandbox.

I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InstanceName should contain QA, UAT, Dev etc.

There is no straight forward way for this.

You can check by InstanceName in the Organization field:

```
SELECT InstanceName FROM Organization
```

Refer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110760/how-to-identify-the-type-of-sandbox-in-apex